# Get number of occurrences of a document based on stipulated rules

Tags: javascript

I'm having a huge difficulty in creating a program to check the number of occurrences of a document based on rules set by me. With the help of regex, I check some fields, and if a particular field exists , I can count the number of occurrences of it, or I create a deeper scan. It's a little confusing, and I do not know exactly how to explain.

I 'm checking text files, but to reduce the complexity , I will use arrays.

I have the following array:

```
[
  'COMPANY: MCDONALDS'  , ID: '12.123.123.1234-12',
  'COMPANY: MCDONALDS'  , ID: '12.123.123.1234-12',
  'COMPANY: BURGERKING' , ID: '12.123.123.1234-12',
]
```

And this is the desire output:

```
{
  'MCDONALDS' :  { '12.123.123.1234-12': 2 },
  'BURGERKING':  { '12.123.123.1234-12': 1 },
}
```

To achieve this, I need to do some checks, so I came up with the following 'MAP':

```
module.exports = [
  {
    'name'  : '\\sCOMPANY:\\s*?([\\w\\s]+)\\s',
    'modifier' : ''
  }
  {
    'name' : '\\sID:\\s*?(\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}\\/\\d{4}-\\d{2})\\s*?',
    'modifier': '',
  }
];
```

I 'm having a hard time creating the last part of code. The biggest problem is because of nested, i'm not finding a way to count the number of docs.

In the last hours I created the following code:

```
var strings  = [
  'COMPANY: MCDONALDS'  , ID: '12.123.123.1234-12',
  'COMPANY: MCDONALDS'  , ID: '12.123.123.1234-12',
  'COMPANY: BURGERKING' , ID: '12.123.123.1234-12'
];


var patterns = [
  [
    {
      'pattern'  : '\\sEMPRESA:\\s*?([\\w\\s]+)\\s',
      'modifier' : ''
    },
    {
      'pattern'  : '\\sINSCRIÇÃO:\\s*(\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}\\/\\d{4}-\\d{2})\\s*?',
      'modifier' : ''
    }
  ]
];

for (var i = 0, var len = string.length; i < len; i++) {

  var string = string[i];
  var _data = {}
  var obj   = _data;

  for (index in pattern) {

    var array = pattern[index];

    for (index_2 in array) {

      var object = array[index_2];
      var last   = +index_2 + 1;
      var result = regex(object.pattern, object.modifier, string);

      if (array[last]) {
        obj = obj[result] = {};
      } else {
        obj[result] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which is very simple. Is iterating over the patterns and creating a object with nested objects, almost like i want:

```
{
  'MCDONALDS' :  { '12.123.123.1234-12': 1 },
  'BURGERKING':  { '12.123.123.1234-12': 1 },
}
```

And if the iteration is the last one, i assign a 1.

The problem is: i have two MCDONALDS, so should be 2, not 1. The second iteration is overwriting the first one, and i can't figure it out how to fix it. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One major issue is not using `var` when declaring local variables. Can run into all sorts of problems and hard to find bugs using globals in a loop

Comment: Hei @charlietfl, thank you for your reply. I fixed, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Alot of times trying to explain your question in a high level way (such as this site) you end up solving it or at least seeing what you did wrong. Just saying...

Comment: I'm still trying to solve here, i can't give up, but i hand would be very nice.

Comment: That initial array syntax is invalid/nonsense. An *actual* sample would help. Misplaced opening `'`?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will help but this does give the desired result

```js
var array = [
  `'COMPANY: MCDONALDS'  , ID: '12.123.123.1234-12'`,
  `'COMPANY: MCDONALDS'  , ID: '12.123.123.1234-12'`,
  `'COMPANY: BURGERKING' , ID: '12.123.123.1234-12'`,
];

var matches ={}
var result = {};

array.forEach(function(x) { 
  var key = x.match(/COMPANY:\s[a-z]+/i)[0].match(/[a-z]+$/i);
  var id = x.match(/ID.*/)[0].match(/\'[0-9\.-]+'$/);
  
  matches[key] = (matches[key] || 0) + 1; 
  result[key] = {
    [id] : matches[key]
  }

});

console.log(result)
```